# unity 3D collider

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[image: Screen From the Game]

i am trying to develop a melee combat game i am using edge collider and below code
i noticed that when i move or enable and disable the collider from the inspector everything goes but when i stand in my palace and use AttackCol.enabled = !AttackCol.enabled; 
i cannot hit and the trigger function do not called
the only difference i see is the collider color when i add it from the inspector  or while i am moving its color is normal but when i enable and disable it by code its color goes pale and do not do anything

```
public virtual void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (DamageSources.Contains( collision.tag ))
        {
            StartCoroutine(TakeDamage());
        }
    }
```

Comment: How does your `TakeDamage()` function look like? :)

Answer (score 2):

- Make sure that your Trigger Game Object is not marked as Static.
- Remove `virtual` from function definition.
- Create another Game Object for Trigger Component and try to change activation of whole the Game Object, not collider component

Comment: why i should remove virtual ?

Comment: a part of documentations: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter2D.html

Answer (score 1):

Stuff like `AttackCol.enabled = !AttackCol.enabled;` is clever, but it can go wrong when that one is called (accidentally) more than once. I suggest trying it out in the simplest form `AttackCol.enabled = true;` to make sure the error is not there. Later you can still make it more elegant again! :)

Answer (score 0):

i added  AttackCol.isTrigger = AttackCol.enabled;
after AttackCol.enabled = !AttackCol.enabled;
and everything geos ok right now 
but i think it is a work around 
but i need to know why the color goes pale ?